# loading dropdown list with data from table in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 models and corresponding tables (EnquiryModel, EmployeeModel, RegionModel).
I want to populate a dropdown list in both the 'create' views of Enquiry and Employee.
That dropdown list should be filled with the data from the 'Region_Name' field in the RegionModel Table.

How can I do this?

I have RegionModel:

```
  namespace MvcConQuery.Models
    {
        [Table("Region_Details")]
        public class RegionModel
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public Int32 Region_id { get; set; }
            public string Region { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And also I have EmployeeModel and EnquiryModel, I give the following code in controller of these models:

```
  public ActionResult Create() 
        { 
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> abc = new SelectList(db.Regions, "Region_id", "Region"); 
        ViewBag.regions = abc; 
        return View(); 
        }
```

I give this code in Create View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("regions","select")
```

But I got the error:

**There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'regions'.**

Please help me to code the Create()function in controller and the Create View.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: yes, I give this in controller:                                public ActionResult Create()
        {
 IEnumerable<SelectListItem> abc = new SelectList(db.Regions, "Region_id", "Region");
            ViewBag.regions = abc;
            return View();
        }

Comment: And I give this code in Create View:                                     @Html.DropDownList("regions","select")

Comment: post some meaningful code and I could help you out

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
 DATAEntities _context = new DATAEntities ();
 var List = (from r in _context.Registrations select r).ToList();
 ViewBag.CustomerName = new SelectList(List, "Region_id", "Region");
```

**View**

```
  @Html.DropDownList("regions", (SelectList)ViewBag.CustomerName, "--Select--")
```

If you have any concerned let me know.